# Create Visual Studio Plugin to write Code automatically

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015

on developing webApis I am always doing the same. I am sure there are better ways but this one is kind of working for me. It is a lot of writing and I hope I find some ways to automate some steps. This is how I do it so far:

First I create the database
Second I create the dataset according to the database
Then I create the Model-classes and the Controllers. Just the representations of the Database and a basic getRowfromDB and setRowToDB functions
Then I start working on my project

I once wrote a programm that reads the database and creates all classes-types-files automated. I just need to copy these files to the project and need to create some querys in the dataset. This saves a lot of time because I don't have to write the same stuff over and over again. Now I want to write it as plugin to Visual Studio. But I have absolutly no idea how to start.

I image something like this:
I create the database as usually. Then I create the dataset and drag and drop all tables in it. (Now the new stuff) I hit a button in Visual Studio that creates a query on each dataset-table to get data for the table by primary ID and then creates one controller and one data-representation for each datatable.

I know how to implement the functions but I don't know how to start programming the plugin. The help on the msdn-sites was kind of confusing. Could you please give me some hints to start in the right direction?

Thank you very much

Florian

Comment: Do you know about EntityFramework?

Comment: I heard the term but never really looked into it. I will check some source, thank you